# Estoy trabajando con reconocimiento de voz de Windows pero el programa no me realiza el evento que debe ocurrir cuando le digo la instrucción

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Estoy trabajando con reconocimiento de voz pero el programa no me realiza el evento que debe ocurrir cuando le digo la instrucción. Me lo realiza después.

Dando mas detalles de como funciona mi programa, este lo que debe hacer es un pase de lista, como para un salon de clase. Donde al decir la instrucción "Iniciar", debe ejecutar el evento llamado Iniciar y comenzar a dictar,dentro de un ciclo for each, los nombres de los alumnos que tengo almacenados en una tabla SQL. Al mencionar a un alumno, tiene que hacer una pausa de 3 segundos para que alguien diga la instruccion "Presente". Si esto ocurre, el programa debe pausar el evento Iniciar para iniciar el evento PresentDetected, que lo que hace es, en mi BD, en la tabla de alumnos, poner un check en el campo Asistencia. Este check se verá reflejado en un DataGridView que tengo en mi form.

Les muestro el ciclo for each:

```
For Each fila As DataGridViewRow In FormPaseDeLista.DataGridView1.Rows
            nombre = ""
            apellidoP = fila.Cells(1).Value.ToString
            apellidoM = fila.Cells(2).Value.ToString
            nombre = fila.Cells(3).Value.ToString
            nombre = apellidoP & " " & apellidoM & " " & nombre

            array(i) = nombre  'Almaceno nombre completo en una posicion de mi array'
            speeker.Speak(array(i)) 'Dicta el nombre del alumno'
            recognition.Enabled = True  'Aqui es donde habilito el reconocedor de voz para que si detecta "Presente", se vaya al evento PresentDetected'

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) 'Espera 3 segundos'
            i += 1    'Avanza al siguiente alumno'
        Next
```

Para comprobar que el evento PresentDetected si funcionó, puse un msgbox avisandome que si entró al evento. Entonces por cada vez que yo diga presente, me debe de mostrar el MsgBox. Este es el codigo del PresentDetected y el evento Presente:

```
 Public Sub PresentDetected(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal r As RecognitionEventArgs)
        If r.Result.Text = "Presente" Then  'Si se detecta "Presente", entonces'
            RaiseEvent presente()      'Ejecutar evento Presente()'
        End If
    End Sub
```

'Este es el evento Presente() donde me pone el check en mi BD.'

```
Private Sub Metodos_presente() Handles Me.presente

    MsgBox(" PresentDetected event has turned on") 
    Dim cadenaUpdate = "update " & FormPaseDeLista.ComboBox1.Text & " set asistencia=1 where ID=" & i   'Actualizar tabla, poner asistencia=1 donde ID al alumno que se acaba de dictar.'
    Dim comandoUpdate As New SqlCommand(cadenaUpdate, con)

    con.Open()
    comandoUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()   'Ejecuta instruccion SQL'
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

El comportamiento sería algo asi:

- PC: Juan Martinez Ramirez
- Yo: Presente
- *PC muestra MsgBox y pone el check en el alumno Juan*
- PC: Pedro Gonzalez
- Yo: Presente PC muestra MsgBox y pone el check en el alumno Pedro
- *PC muestra MsgBox y pone el check en el alumno Pedro*

Y asi sucesivamente. El problema es que, cuando está dictando los nombres de los alumnos y yo digo presente en el momento que debe ser, no se marca el check en ese alumno pero si detecta que yo digo la instruccion Presente. Entonces termina de dictar todos los nombres, y si yo dije 5 veces "Presente", al terminar el ciclo me muestra 5 MsgBox's y solo pone el check a la ultima persona de la lista.

El problema debe estar en el for each. Pero no encuentro cual sea la solución...Según yo, debo pausar el evento Iniciar cuando el programa diga a un alumno e iniciar el evento PresentDetected() para que evalúe si se dijo o no la instruccion. Y despues de analizarlo, volver a reanudar el evento Iniciar para que siga con el siguiente alumno.

Les dejo el codigo completo:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Speech.Synthesis
Imports System.Speech.Recognition
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class Metodos
   Dim con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.easylistBDConnectionString)  'Declaro la conexion'
   Public speeker As New SpeechSynthesizer()
   Dim i = 0


   Dim recognition As New SpeechRecognizer
   Dim gram As Grammar
   ' events'
   Public Event SpeechRecognized As _
       EventHandler(Of SpeechRecognizedEventArgs)
   Public Event presente()


   ' word list'
   Dim wordlist As String() = New String() {"Presente"}


   Public Sub Iniciar(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RecognitionEventArgs)
       MsgBox("Iniciar detectado")
       Dim apellidoP = ""
       Dim apellidoM = " "
       Dim nombre = " "
       Dim array(FormPaseDeLista.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) As String


       ' convert the word list into a grammar'
       Dim words As New Choices(wordlist)
       gram = New Grammar(New GrammarBuilder(words))
       recognition.LoadGrammar(gram)

       'Declarar deteccion a español.'
       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("es-ES")
       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("es-ES")

       'Propiedades del speaker'
       speeker.Rate = 1
       speeker.Volume = 100
       speeker.SelectVoiceByHints(2)

       i = 0
       AddHandler recognition.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf PresentDetected

       For Each fila As DataGridViewRow In FormPaseDeLista.DataGridView1.Rows
           nombre = ""
           apellidoP = fila.Cells(1).Value.ToString
           apellidoM = fila.Cells(2).Value.ToString
           nombre = fila.Cells(3).Value.ToString
           nombre = apellidoP & " " & apellidoM & " " & nombre

           array(i) = nombre  'Almaceno nombre completo en una posicion de mi array'
           speeker.Speak(array(i)) 'Dicta el nombre '
           recognition.Enabled = True

           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
           i += 1
       Next

   End Sub


   Public Sub PresentDetected(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal r As RecognitionEventArgs)
       If r.Result.Text = "Presente" Then
           RaiseEvent presente()
       End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub Metodos_presente() Handles Me.presente

       MsgBox(" PresentDetected event has turned on")
       Dim cadenaUpdate = "update " & FormPaseDeLista.ComboBox1.Text & " set asistencia=1 where ID=" & i
       Dim comandoUpdate As New SqlCommand(cadenaUpdate, con)

       con.Open()
       comandoUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
       con.Close()

   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Pausar el evento seria como llamar al otro evento? o sea, si llamas al otro evento, el original se pausa, ya que estan en el mismo hilo....

Comment: Quiero pausar el evento iniciar al momento de que me dicte al primer alumno. Que se espere unos 2 segundos para que yo diga "Presente" y despues reanude el evento iniciar. Como puedo pausarlo? Estuve intentando con el System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() pero no se bien de esto. No domino el uso de eventos ni tampoco el uso de hilos. Lo que he programado lo he sacado con ayuda de internet y por mi cuenta.

Comment: Yo aca no veo ni eventos ni hilos. Solo veo una funcion, y cuando llamas a otra funcion, la funcion que se estaba ejecutando espera al regreso de la otra. Si pausas con sleep, tu programa se va a quedar muerto. Creo que lo que buscas es que la funcion SpeakAsync (que es asincronica) espere a que realmente le hablen para que reanude la ejecucion. Esto es mucho mas complicado y requiere saber de await task.

Comment: Mira, ya actualice el codigo a como lo tengo ahorita. Si gustas volver a leer la descripcion. Añadí tambien el codigo completo para que veas que están los eventos que te mencione anteriormente. Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: El addhandler deberia estar afuera del for. Si no estas creando un manejador de evento por cada vuelta. Y no se si puedo ayudarte mas porque no se como funcionan esos componentes que tenes. El sleep dudo que deba existir, pero no puedo asegurarlo. Ya que es un metodo asincronido, deberia se manejado con await y task.

Comment: La cosa no está en el metodo asincrono. El metodo SpeakAsync es independiente del evento que me ayudará a marcar el check en mi BD. Aqui el problema es como hacerle para detectar presente por cada vuelta que de en el ciclo para la lista. Dejame checar si encuentro algun metodo que se lleve task o await.